# Am I executing celery shared tasks correct?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat, periodic-task

Here is the way how I start celery periodic tasks. First I execute this command:

```
celery worker -A my_project.celery
```

And after that this command:

```
celery -A my_project beat -l info -S django
```

After executing these two commands on two different terminal tabs, my celery beat periodic tasks starts running. If I don't run one of the described commands, my periodic tasks do not run. My question is: is there any any way to start the celery with the single command, or even better with runserver command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of using Celery is correct. You can use parameter `-B, --beat` to start beat and worker using single command:

```
# This will start worker AND beat process
celery worker --app=my_project -l=INFO --beat -S django
```

But **do not use** this in production, see this note in Celery docs (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html):

> `-B` is meant to be used for development purposes. **For production environment, you need to start celery beat separately**.

Few notes: 1) I think there is no way to run the Celery and `runserver` together (I honestly think it's not a good idea); 2) I see `django-celery` tag in your question. This is and old and deprecated way of integrating Django and Celery:

> THIS PROJECT IS ONLY REQUIRED IF YOU WANT TO USE DJANGO RESULT BACKEND
>   AND ADMIN INTEGRATION (Source: https://github.com/celery/django-celery)

Comment: Thank you sir! My issue was unrelated to this question, but due to your answer I've been able to remedy an issue dogging me for weeks!